# Execution failed for task dexdebug

Tags: android

I just opened a new project in android studio, and i didn`t write a single letter and I already got an error : Execution failed for task dexdebug. Can`t figure out how to solve this one, I`m an Eclipse guy but it made me go crazy so I moved to Android Studio.

Here are my pages :

http://pastebin.com/ZR81eFzA

Comment: Please can anyone help me ??? I`m desprate I can`t fix it

Comment: you should expecify more, but look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488388/android-studio-gradle-dependency-error