# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Why is this error happening?

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1576)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5931)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/main_background"
>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/history"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never"

   />
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.calculator3"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
  compile files('libs/arity-2.1.2.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: please provide more information. Your java code and also xml code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490600/error-inflating-class-recyclerview)

Comment: simply use its dependency instead of providing it only jar file... dont complicate things, then clean or rebuild project.

Comment: Are you getting `ClassNotFoundException`? Please post the entire stacktrace (you've only posted half of it)